# Partial update to extended user profile

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a extension to user model in Django, adding multiple fields to the regular user profile. In order for the user to be able to change them, I have created a form that should be able to modify those fields but with no success...

models.py

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    license_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    # חפ
    pi_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    reason_pension = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    reason_policy = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    reason_gemel = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    reason_hishtalmot = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    customer_name = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "שם לקוח",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    labelwhite = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    smoker = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "מעשן",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    ensurence_amount = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "ביטוח חיים",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    ensurence_amount1 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "00000",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    disability_amount = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "נכות מתאונה",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = LifeEnsurenceModel
        fields = ('customer_name', 'smoker', 'ensurence_amount', 'disability_amount', 'death_amount')

# agent profile forms
class AgentProfileEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    agency_name = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    license_number = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    phone = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    phone2 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    fax = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    reason_pension = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    address = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    city = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    zip_code = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    about = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    pi_id = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    reason_pension = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    reason_policy = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    reason_gemel = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))
    reason_hishtalmot = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "קרן השתלמות",
            "class": "form-control",
            "input type": "text"
        }
    ))
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileModel
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def agent_profile(request):
    user_id =  request.user.id
    msg = None
    success = False
    user = UserProfileModel.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
    print(type(user))
    print(user.user_id)
    print(user.reason_hishtalmot)
    context = {}
    load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
    context['segment'] = load_template
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("New POST request")
        print(request.POST)
        form = AgentProfileEdit(request.POST, instance=user)
        print(form.data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            msg = 'WOWOWOWOWW'
            success = True
            print(msg)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/agent_profile.html")

        else:
            msg = 'Form is not valid'
            print(msg)
    else:
        print(msg)
        print("Im here")
        form = AgentProfileEdit()

    return render(request, "home/agent_profile.html", {"form": form, "msg": msg, "success": success})
```

form validation fails every time even though user information is correct

tried using instance=user (and any other attributes from it).

Comment: Have your tried print(form.errors) and print(form.non_field_errors) to see where your data might be having issues?

Comment: Tried, getting the following:
<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <AgentProfileEdit bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(user;agency_name;license_number;phone;phone2;fax;address;city;zip_code;about;pi_id;reason_pension;reason_policy;reason_gemel;reason_hishtalmot)>>
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sK6hluFCykByC49q6aDG5FTUVvKigZvkj7L0NS8d8P1D8nNtVMEse7LoZVNBiwAw'], 'reason_hishtalmot': ['1232143']}>
Form is not valid

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only filling in one field in the form that requires all fields.  However, your model does not except blank values, only null values. If you do want them to accept empty fields from forms, then you have to use blank=True rather than null = True.

Additionally, you probably want to include the instance in the default form also.

```
else:
    print(msg)
    print("Im here")
    form = AgentProfileEdit(instance = user)
```

This means that any fields that aren't empty in the DB are pre-filled out (and won't be replaced by empty ones if you enter just one field.

Don't forget you can also use `{{form.errors}}` and `{{form.non_field_errors}}` in your template for further debugging.